# SQL- joins vs updating a table

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm terribly confused right now. I've quiet some theoretical knowledge and am not able to exert it right know. I know how to get wanted result tables with SQL, but that's not handy for storing the information. Also how to process it in a program.  I get no connection between the different abstraction layers in my brain...

I've a database **A** with a table, let's call it **sales**. And I have a database **B** with a table called **bills**. (While DB *A* is used by a complex shop software, it's more safe to not modify the structure or botch around with it's data, I want to copy regularly only the relevant information in my own DB *B*.) *B.bills* is just a tiny subset of *A.sales* + 3 further columns.

Now the updated table information would be a     `LEFT JOIN ON sales.id=bills.id`, but that's a table. How do I store the data in *B.bills*?
Or am I barking up the wrong tree?  And I should update for each *sales.id* the *bills.id* in php instead of SQL. Because all I can imagine at the moment would result in `#ids²` SQL-operations. And that can't be the best way. (And wouldn't even the proposed php-approach result in (worst-case)     `#ids²`    SQL-operations? Or would *bills.id* as a primary key limit it's seek to constant time?)

If anyone could help me lifting the fog I'm lost in, I would be very happy!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are asking for. You want to copy data from `A.sales` to `B.bills`?

Comment: An easy way of doing this is `INSERT INTO B.bills (column_names)  SELECT column_names FROM A.sales`

Comment: There's records in `Bills` and there are records in `Sales` and you are wanting to get the resultset of the join between them? Are you certain that `sales.id` have matches to `bills.id`. Generally order id's are different then billing document ids in most systems. If you joined the two, and the id's are the same between an order and it's bill, then you shouldn't get #ids², at worst you would get `sales*avg number of bills per sales order`

Comment: yep, I want to copy from     `A.sales`     to     `B.bills`    .  Nobody  than me touches B, so there is no danger of confusing diffrent "bills"-tables. It was just for a more distinct declaration.       `INSERT INTO B.bills (column_names)`   will do the trick. Thank you!